# Tons of errors in xtr1common when building OpenCV 3.2 in VS2015 Update 3

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

When building a simple OpenCV app in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, with OpenCV 3.2, with target x64 (there are no x86 libs in 3.2 release), I get the following errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(100): error C2737: 'std::is_same_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(100): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_same_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(245): error C2737: 'std::is_integral_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(245): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_integral_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(282): error C2737: 'std::is_floating_point_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(282): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_floating_point_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(295): error C2737: 'std::is_arithmetic_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common(295): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_arithmetic_v': cannot be a template definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstddef(697): error C2737: 'std::is_function_v': 'constexpr' object must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstddef(697): error C2998: 'const bool std::is_function_v': cannot be a template definition
```

Somehow I dont believe this is a problem with OpenCV, so I guess I am missing something in the build process or have something misconfigured. Any suggestions what should be changed are appreciated :)

I followed the following site http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html when it comes to suggestions how to configure VS.

Adding source code, though I believe this is something related to configuration of the build, not to the source code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get the same errors when adding OpenCV 3.1 through Nuget as described in [OpenCV via NuGet packages with Visual Studio 2015, how to configure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317398/opencv-via-nuget-packages-with-visual-studio-2015-how-to-configure/42324201#comment73139150_42324201) . Interesting enough it looks like similar errors where seen in completely different cases - [Visual Studio 2015: C++ REST API (Casablanca) failing compilation in VS inlcudes/headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747680/visual-studio-2015-c-rest-api-casablanca-failing-compilation-in-vs-inlcudes) and where solved by reinstalling VS2015 from RC to full community edition. I am using VS2015 Enterprise Update 3 so I hope is not the root cause...

Comment: How do you expect us to answer *anything* from that without seeing your code? Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) at a minimum.

Comment: I've added source code ;-)

Comment: Get rid of `stdafx.h`; it sometimes causes problems.

Comment: I got rid of stdafx,h, disabled precompiled headers, still the same set of errors there :( Any additional suggestion appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was apparently caused by issues with VS2015. At least after I did repair of the VS2015 installation (from `Program and Features` in Windows, the problem is gone)